# Does memory address translation need extra access to memory?

Tags: virtual-memory

I've got a question about virtual memory management, more specifically, the address translation.

When an application runs, the CPU receives instructions containing virtual memory addresses, and translates them into physical addresses via the page table.

My question is, since the page table also aside at a memory block, does that means the CPU has to access the memory twice in a single memory-access instruction? If the answer is no, then how does this actually work? Which part did I miss?

Could anyone give me some details about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual the answer is neither yes or no.

Worst case you have to do a walk of the page table, which is indeed stored in (some kind of) memory, this is not necessarily only one lookup, it can be multiple lookups, see for example a [two-level table](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/X86_Paging_4K.svg) (example from wikipedia).

However, typically this page table is accompanied by a hardware assist called the [translation lookaside buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer), this is essentially a cache for the page table, the lookup process can be seen in [this image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Page_table_actions.svg). It works just as you would expect a cache too work, if a lookup succeeds you happily continue with the physical fetch, if it fails you proceed to the aforementioned page walk and you update the cache afterwards.

This hardware assist is usually implemented as a [CAM (Content Addressable Memory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory), something that's most used in network processing but is also very useful here. It is a memory-component that does not do the lookup based upon an address but based upon 'content', or any generic key (the keys dont' have to be contiguous, incrementing numbers). In this case the key would be your virtual address, and the resulting memory lookup would be your physical address. As this CAM is a separate component and as it is very fast you could state that as long as you hit it you don't incur any extra memory overhead for virtual -> physical address translation.

You could ask why they don't put the whole page table in a CAM? Quite simply, CAM's are both quite expensive and more importantly quite energy-hungry, so you don't want to make them too big (we wouldn't want a laptop that requires 1KW to run do we?).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes.

The MMU contains a cache of virtual to physical address mapping, called a TLB (Translation Lookaside Buffer).

If the page in question is not in the TLB (a TLB miss), then it needs to load the relevant piece of page table from main memory into that cache first, which will need additional memory access.

Finally, if the page cannot be found at all, a trap is issued to the CPU (a page fault), and the CPU have an opportunity to fix this - e.g. allocate memory, load the piece from a file, swap space and similar.

The details on how this is done varies between architectures, on some, the TLB miss also involves the CPU to configure the TLB, though on most this is automatic. (but the CPU would have to flush the TLB when doing a context switch, and load a new pagetable for e.g. a new process)

More info e.g. here https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html